# How to do functional testing for a website?

Tags: testing, functional-testing

Just wanted to know how you could do functional testing for a website. For example I have list of functional and non - functional requirements but I have no idea of how to actually write the tests for these requirements using Functional Tests. Could you please show me some examples which could improve my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: What language is used to write your application?

Comment: PHP, HTML, javascript, SQL, css and AJAX.